# How to check that pandas DataFrame field is a digit and isn't empty?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
col1   col2   col3
50     dd     3
2      r      NaN
5      d      4
a      e      5
```

I need to calculate the mean value for selected columns `cols`. And then I should check if any of the values in selected rows deviate from the median value by more than 20%.

I am not sure how to tackle mixed values in a single row to make these calculations.

```
def test_row(x, threshold):
    if x.dtype == int or x.dtype == float:
        return x > threshold

columns = ["col1", "col3"]
for col in columns:
    threshold = df[col].median()*(20/100)
    check = df.apply(lambda x: test_row(x[col], threshold), axis=1)
    print(check.any())
```

However it obviously fails because `if x.dtype == int or x.dtype == float` does not work.

Comment: your code raises a value error here: `threshold = df[col].median()*(20/100)` before the function is even run

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Do you know how to fix it? I don't want to replace NaN by 0. Just to skip them.

Comment: The problem that @Chris has signaled is in col1 having 'a'. You can fix change the type column using `pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: @Terry. Will this code just return all numeric values?

Comment: he will convert to numeric, what he can't convert, will return as NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function could be:

```
def test_row(x, threshold):
    if isinstance(x,(int,float)) and x:
        return x > threshold
```

The second logic in function is just for check if x contains something, if its empty it will return *False*.